# Transform a dataframe with comma thousand separator to space separator Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, integer, separator

I have an issue with format in Pandas. So, I have a Column in A DataFrame witch countains numbers with a comma seperator like (200,000). So I would like to transfom this in (200 000).

The easy way it's to use the replace function but I want also to transform the type into Integer. It's not working because there are spaces between.

In the end, I just want to do a ranking with descending sorted values ​​like this:

| Id | Villas | Price_nospace |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Peace | 35000000 |
| 3 | Peace | 35000000 |
| 2 | Rosa | 27000000 |
| 1 | Beach | 25000000 |
| 0 | Palm | 22000000 |

As you can see, It's not easy to read the price without separator. So I would like to make the price more readable. But when I have space separator I can't convert to Int.
And If I don't convert to integer, I can use sort_values function. So I am stuck.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `df['Price_nospace']=df['Price_nospace'].str.replace(',','',regex=True).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Modified the sample input a bit to sort(descending) the values in output.

Below solution will sort(descending) the dataframe by `Price_nospace` and replace the `comma` with `space`. But the `Price_nospace` will be of `object` type in output.

**Sample Input**

```
Id  Villas  Price_nospace
0   3   Peace   220,000
1   3   Peace   350,000
2   2   Rosa    270,000
3   1   Beach   250,000
4   0   Palm    230,000
```

**Code**

```
df['Price_new'] = df['Price_nospace'].str.replace(',','',regex=True).astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(by='Price_new', ascending=False)
df['Price_nospace'] = df['Price_nospace'].str.replace(',',' ',regex=True)
df = df.drop(columns='Price_new').reset_index(drop=True) ## reset_index, if required
df
```

**Output**

```
    Id  Villas  Price_nospace
0   3   Peace   350 000
1   2   Rosa    270 000
2   1   Beach   250 000
3   0   Palm    230 000
4   3   Peace   220 000
```

**Explanation**

Introduced a new column `Price_new` to convert `Price_nospace` values to int and sort the values.
Once df is sorted, just replaced `comma with space for Price_nospace` and deleted temp column `Price_new`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to alter how the data is *displayed* but not affect the underlying type.

Use [`pd.options.display.float_format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options) after converting the `str` prices to `float` prices:

```
import pandas as pd


def my_float_format(x):
    '''
    Number formatting with custom thousands separator
    '''
    return f'{x:,.0f}'.replace(',', ' ')


# set display float_format
pd.options.display.float_format = my_float_format

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': [3, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    'Villas': ['Peace', 'Peace', 'Rosa', 'Beach', 'Palm'],
    'Price_nospace': ['35,000,000', '35,000,000', '27,000,000',
                      '25,000,000', '22,000,000']
})

# Convert str prices to float
df['Price_nospace'] = (
    df['Price_nospace'].str.replace(',', '', regex=True).astype(float)
)
```

---

`Output`:

```
print(df)

   Id Villas  Price_nospace
0   3  Peace     35 000 000
1   3  Peace     35 000 000
2   2   Rosa     27 000 000
3   1  Beach     25 000 000
4   0   Palm     22 000 000
```

```
print(df.dtypes)

Id                 int64
Villas            object
Price_nospace    float64
dtype: object
```

Since the type is `float64` any numeric operations will function as normal.

---

The same `my_float_format` function can be used on export as well:

```
df.to_csv(float_format=my_float_format)
```

```
,Id,Villas,Price_nospace
0,3,Peace,35 000 000
1,3,Peace,35 000 000
2,2,Rosa,27 000 000
3,1,Beach,25 000 000
4,0,Palm,22 000 000
```